# Prevent Terraform from destroying specific resources

Tags: terraform, destroy

I am trying to prevent the specific resources from getting destroyed when doing "terraform destroy".

Any suggestions on how this can be achieved will be very helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: First google result: https://coderbook.com/@marcus/prevent-terraform-from-recreating-or-deleting-resource/

Answer (score 2):

You can remove resources, you want to keep active, from the state and just destroy the ones you leave active. When removing a resource from the state, terraform does not manage this resource anymore and hence won't destroy it.

```
terraform state rm <resource>
```

Documentation can be found here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/rm.html

```
terraform state --help
```

shows you a list of options to manually manipulate the state.

Attention: this can lead to data loss. But I guess, you are fine as destruction is your goal. Enjoy.

Attention: this can be costly if you forget about the resources you kept running.